# how to get a fullscreen treeview in tkinter with a button underneath it

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

so im trying to show a treeview fullscreen on a raspberry pi touchscreen. the treeview would be populated with items my script reads from a csv file. when a line contains a specific item there would be an alarm (using the gpio pins). this all works, now there should be a button beneath the treeview to reset the alarm.

this is the code for the tkinter part of the script, the function of the reset button works, it just won't show on my display. when i disable the treeview, the button appears,; so i suspect there should be an error in my coding of this component.

```
mainScreen=tk.Tk()
mainScreen.title("Meldingen")
mainScreen.overrideredirect(True)
mainScreen.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(mainScreen.winfo_screenwidth(), mainScreen.winfo_screenheight()))
mainScreen.resizable(width=False, height=False)
s=ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('Treeview', rowheight=40)

header=["time","alarm","adress","message"]
tree=ttk.Treeview(mainScreen,columns=header, show="headings")
tree.pack(padx=20, pady=20,fill="x")
reset_button=tk.Button(mainScreen,text="reset alarm",command=reset_alarm,state= tk.DISABLED)
reset_button.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
```